# Performance of calling a function from class

Tags: c#, .net, function, performance, time

Does calling a function from a class with hundreds of functions run slower than calling a function from a class with one function?

Comment: No. Number of functions is irrelevant.  Unless those functions call each other, then yes, it might matter (although the difference will be noticable only in hardcore loops). That being said who writes code with hundreds of functions on a class?

Comment: The functions (aka methods) in a class are arranged into a.method table during compilation. When you call a method, the address of the method is looked up and used in the call. I'm about 99% sure that the lookup is **O(1)**

Comment: Why have you asked? What issue are your seeing? What concern do you have? How is this practical to you?

Comment: I am writing "Input" code in "godot engine". For more flexibility, I wanted to define this part of the code in my public class(Autoload class) so that I don't need to rewrite them in future projects.

Comment: @cynerboy - Sorry, is that an answer to my questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the number of functions in a class does not change the performance. After JIT Compilation the MethodTable is not needed any more to call a function.

Things are changing of course if you use reflection to call a function!

You can read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/may/net-framework-internals-how-the-clr-creates-runtime-objects